# QML - Create ListModel dynamically (JAVASCRIPT issue)

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

Here is my code, and it works!

```
ListModel {
    id: idValueList

    Component.onCompleted: {

        for (var i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
            append(createListElement(i));
        }
    }

    function createListElement(id) {
        return {
            myId: id + 1, myValue: ""
        };
    }
}
```

However, I need to substitute the "21" in the for loop with `myXmlListModel.get(myXmlListModel.count - 1).myValue`, which comes from an XmlListModel, the dynamic list model stop working!

The funny part is that the code

```
Text{
    x:0 ; y:0
    text: myXmlListModel.get(myXmlListModel.count - 1).myValue;
}
```

prints for me exactly a 21. But if I use the expression `myXmlListModel.get(myXmlListModel.count - 1).myValue` in the for loop, nothing works.

How can it be possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason should be quite easy to understand:

```
Component.onCompleted: [...]
```

is executed at a very specific point in time, when the component is completed.
This is not necessarily the point in time, at which the content of the `myXmlListModel` is available. It might be allready created, but might still be empty. Therefor when

```
Component.onCompleted: [...]
```

of your `ListModel` is executed, the `myXmlListModel.count` is indeed still `0`, while changing to 21 right after - so at the time you read the `Text` it already has the right amount.

The point in time where you should fill your `ListModel` is therefor not, when it is completed, but once the content is ready, so you might handle:

```
myXmlListModel.onCompleted
```

and

```
myXmlListModel.onCountChanged
```

(for the latter you should consider to call `clear()` on your `ListModel` first)